# After using find(), how do I extract the next line from the webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use beautiful soup to extract data about characters. I am searching for the word "Age" and then extracting the value, but I cannot seem to extract the value. The code is:

```
<h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Age</h3>
<div class="pi-data-value pi-font">
    17 (Arc 1-2)
```

I want to extract the 17, how do I do this?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import urllib.parse, urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googlesearch import search

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')

@client.command()
async def check(ctx, *, name):

    for i in search(name, tld='com', lang='en', num=1, stop=10, pause=2):
        url = i
        print(url)

    site = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site, 'html.parser')
    #age = soup.find("h3", text="Age").next_sibling(strip=False)
    age = soup.find_next_sibling("Age")

    await ctx.send(age)
```

I have two different HTML layouts:

```
<b>Age</b>
<td width="60px" style="background:#DE1C4E; color: #FFFFFF"><b>Age</b>
</td>
<td width="140px" style="background:#E5E4E2; border: 1px solid #17317E">16
<p>17 (from Chapter 79 onwards)
</p>
</td>
16
```

And

```
<h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Age</h3>
<div class="pi-data-value pi-font">17 (Arc 1-2)<br>18 (Arc 3-4)<br>19 (Arc 5+)</div>
17 (Arc 1-2)
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have already tried and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I will add the code to the question! for context, I am making a discord bot for my friends to search for characters from shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the next tag that comes *after* the `h3`, you can use the [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<h3 class="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font">Age</h3>
<div class="pi-data-value pi-font">
    17 (Arc 1-2)
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(
    soup.find("h3", class_="pi-data-label pi-secondary-font")
    .find_next("div", class_="pi-data-value pi-font")
    .get_text(strip=True)
)
```

Output:

```
17 (Arc 1-2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to skip a line, to go from one text to another

Comment: Because for some characters, there is a line of HTML that separate the word "age" and the number

Comment: @Luke You can pass a class-name to `find_next()`. I edited my answer. See if that works

Comment: So, this works for some but not all. Is there a way to look for strings in the find_next?

Comment: @Luke Can you edit your question with more of the HTML as an example

Comment: I have attempted to update, I need to search for age, then take out the value

Comment: With your updated examples, the value is the first digit that comes right after "age"?  You expected output is `age` `16` (first example)  and `age` `17` (second example) ?

Comment: Thanks to you, I have managed to sort it. I am using an if statement to see if the returned value is an integer. I used both .find_next("div") and .find_next("td") to establish a difference